# convert days to weeks in python

Tags: python

On the first line, ask the user how many days they've been driving for and declare the user input. It's an integer, so cast the string.

Then calculate the number of years in that set of days.

Next, convert the remaining days that weren't converted to years into weeks.

Then, get any remaining days that weren't converted to weeks.

I've done everything this asks, and my classes system is telling me i'm not doing any of it even though I get the same output it is looking for

```
'''The program converts days you have been driving for to weeks and years'''
print("Days you have been driving: 1000")
days=1000
years=days//365
weeks=days%365//7
consDays=days%365%7
print("You have been driving for:")
print("Years:" , years)
print("Weeks:" , weeks)
print("Days:" , consDays)
```

i get exactly the output i need but for some reason i'm not being credited for it.

Comment: Are you supposed to hard code `days` or accept it as a parameter, or get it from the user?

Comment: How do you suppose we're meant to know what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Where have you `ask the user how many days they've been driving` ??

Comment: That is part of my problem is I have no idea, coding is like a foreign language to me and this is my 2nd day in this class, and my professor has been completely unresponsive to any questions.

Comment: I'm assuming my issue lies somewhere in the area of asking the user how many day's they've been driving, and casting a string, but I have no idea what that evemn means

Comment: The directions I posted are the exact directions of my assignment copied and pasted

Answer (score 3):

Your calculation is wrong.

```
days = int(input("Days you have been driving: "))
years=days//365
weeks=days//7
consDays=days%7
print("You have been driving for:")
print("Years:" , years)
print("Weeks:" , weeks)
print("Days:" , consDays)
```

OUTPUT (for input `1000`)

```
You have been driving for:
Years: 2
Weeks: 142
Days: 6
```